# Is it possible Android app support different version with different apk?

Tags: android, crosswalk

**Android Kitkat** does't support upload in `webview`. I fixed it [Embebed Crosswalk Webview](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/downloads.php). But I want crosswalk work only Kitkat. Is it possible Android app support different version with different apk? Can I upload it Play Store in same app?

Comment: just check what API version the user has and then do stuff differently based on that

Comment: playstore does not support this... so write logic in code on the basis of  API version

Comment: My normal APK file size is 1.5 MB, But with crosswalk 47MB. I want only Kitkat user download big apk, Chromium webview work good than corsswalk.

Comment: I suggest going through this link first https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/index.html , to see if that covers all aspect of your problem.

Comment: I already looked that link. Thanks suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of deploying several apks, you could handle this logic in code with something like this:

```
private final int sdkVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (sdkVersion < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    //do old way
} else {
    //do new way
}
```

More information here: [How to support multiple android version in your code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552250/how-to-support-multiple-android-version-in-your-code)

Comment: I now this method, But I don't want change my all code. When I changed my code will confused and dilate (grow). My question is **Is it possible** Android app support different version with different apk?